# Terraform Helm set tolerations

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, helm

I'm trying to set `tolerations` values in Terraform Helm for the [occm chart](https://github.com/kubernetes/cloud-provider-openstack/tree/master/charts/openstack-cloud-controller-manager) in the following way:

```
set {
  name = "tolerations"
  value = yamlencode([
    {
      key    = "node.kubernetes.io/test"
      value  = "true"
      effect = "NoSchedule"
    }
  ])
}
```

And it fails with the following error:

```
... invalid type for io.k8s.api.core.v1.PodSpec.tolerations: got "string", expected "array"
```

I tried also with:

```
set_list {
  name = "tolerations"
  value = [
    yamlencode({
      key    = "node.kubernetes.io/test"
      value  = "true"
      effect = "NoSchedule"
    })
  ]
}
```

But I get:

```
... invalid type for io.k8s.api.core.v1.Toleration: got "string", expected "map"
```

Now I looked to this [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71126527/terraform-helm-chart-set-value-tolerations) post, but they use different methods. Is there a way to make it work with `set` or `set_list`? What am I doing wrong?